# ps output is not correlated to free command?

Tags: linux, memory, ps

I am getting sum of all reserved memory in KBs by using following command:-

```
ps aux --sort -rss | awk '{sum +=$6} END {print sum}'
OUTPUT: 14746220 i.e. 14.74GB
```

However `free -g returns 27GB` as used. Why there is a difference between the two outputs? Doesn't ps shows all the memory allocation?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same situation. `htop` and `top` both reported about 95% usage (excluding buffers/caches) as did `free -m`. When summing up the processes from `ps`, I only was using about 10% of the memory. I found these sites to be invaluable:

- http://www.linuxatemyram.com/
- https://linux-mm.org/Low_On_Memory

In my case it was the dentries/inode cache that was filling the memory. I don't know why `free` didn't count these as buffers/cache. You can flush this information with the following command, which does not hurt the system:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Information about this is detailed here: https://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches